# Using ReactiveForms, how to set value in HTML angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-reactive-forms

I'm trying to set a value on my HTML. How do I achieve this? I'm using reactive forms on my typescript and have already tried `[value]= "coursemodules.course.id"` in my HTML but it does not seem to work. It does not retrieve it when I `console.log()` it.

**component.ts**

```js
@Input() coursemodules: any = []

moduleForm = new FormGroup({
  class_id: new FormControl(''),
  coursemodule_title: new FormControl(''),
  coursemodule_course_id: new FormControl('')
});

constructor(private coursemoduleService: CoursemoduleapiService) {}

ngOnInit() {}

saveModuleForm() {
  console.log(this.moduleForm.value);
  this.coursemoduleService.createCourseModules(
    this.moduleForm.get('class_id').value,
    this.moduleForm.get('coursemodule_title').value,
    this.moduleForm.get('coursemodule_course_id').value).subscribe(
      result => console.log(result),
      error => console.log(error)
    );
}
```

**HTML**

```html
<form [formGroup]="moduleForm" (ngSubmit)="saveModuleForm()">

    <div class="modal-body m-3">

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="form-label">Class ID</label>
            <input formControlName="class_id" type="text" 
                   class="form-control"
                   placeholder="Class ID">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="form-label">Module Title</label>
            <input formControlName="coursemodule_title" type="text" 
                   class="form-control" 
                   placeholder="Module Title">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="form-label">Course ID</label>
            <input formControlName="coursemodule_course_id" type="text" 
                   class="form-control"
                   [value]="coursemodules.course.id">
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save changes</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: The first thing you do is assign an empty array `coursemodules` and then access it like you do an object. While JS will allow this, this isn't how you should work with arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know `coursemodules` will be ready on `OnInit` you could do:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.moduleForm.patchValue({
        coursemodule_course_id: this.coursemodules[0].course.id
    })
}
```

Alternatively, hook into `ngOnChanges`

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    if (changes.coursemodules && changes.coursemodules.currentValue) {
        ...same as ngOnInit
    }
}
```

---

It should be noted when you do

`class_id: new FormControl('')`

you're giving the control value `''`. You could do `class_id: new FormControl(6)` etc.

Don't use `[value]` alongside formControlName unless you know what your doing

Don't use the `any` type. Create interfaces e.g interface `CourseModule` and then:

```
@Input() coursemodules: CourseModule[] = []
```

This will correctly error on trying `this.coursemodules.course.id`.

Comment: It works! But I'm getting this error TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined on my console. How to resolve this?

Comment: It means whichever line you're getting the TypeError error that `this.coursemodules[0].course` (or whatever you are trying to do `.id` on) is undefined.

Comment: This is my Course Models: `export interface Course {
 id: number;
 courseCode: string;
 courseName: string;
 courseDescription: string;
 course_created_by: string;
 course_date_created: Date;
 course_last_modified: Date;

}`. This is my CourseModule Models: `import { Course } from './Course';

export interface CourseModule {
  id: number;
  class_id: string;
  coursemodule_title: string;
  coursemodule_created_by: number;
  course: {
   [key: string]: Course
  }
}
` but now its saying Property 'course' does not exist on Type CourseModule: []

Comment: it may be worth asking as separate typescript question but I recommend logging `coursemodules` before the error to see what you can access and if it's defined and/or using a [typescript playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use formname.setValue({})

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you remove the `[value]="coursemodules.course.id"` as it will not work with a reactive form. It might show in the form, but a reactive form maintains its own state/values for a form and by using `[value]` you bypass that. If you wish to assign an initial value to a form field you will have to do this in the controller and not in the template.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.moduleForm.get('coursemodule_course_id').setValue(this.coursemodules.course.id)
}
```